# On the zeros of Bessel functions of parameter $\nu=-1/3$

Tags: stochastic-processes, roots, special-functions, mathematical-physics, bessel-functions

Working in a problem I found with the task of finding the zeros of a sum of the Airy functions ( [See for example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airy_function)) $\sqrt{3}\text{Ai}(x)+\text{Bi}(x)$, it result that these are exactly the zeros for the modified Bessel function of the First Kind of parameter $\nu=-1/3$ this is $$I_{-1/3}(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n}}{n !} \frac{(x / 2)^{2 n-1/3}}{\Gamma(n-\frac{1}{3}+1)}$$.

Do you know if there is an expression for the zeros of this function with this specific value of parameter?

**Added:** With computational calculation it looks like that if $\lambda_n$ are the zeros then $|\lambda_n-\lambda_{n+1}|\to \pi.$ Looking for I already found that the zeros have the following expresion $z_{\nu, k}=\left\{k+\frac{1}{2}\left(\nu-\frac{1}{2}\right)\right\} \pi-\frac{4 \nu^{2}-1}{8\left\{k+\frac{1}{2}\left(\nu-\frac{1}{2}\right)\right\} \pi}+O\left(\frac{1}{k^{3}}\right)$.

Comment: There is no closed form for the zeros of Bessel functions.

Answer (score 1):

If you consider Wolfram language functions a closed form, then there is  [**Bessel Y Zero $\text y_{v,x}$**](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=BesselYZero):

$$\def\Ai{\text{Ai}} \def\Bi{\text{Bi}} \sqrt3\Ai(x)+\Bi(x)=0\implies -\sqrt3=\frac{\Bi(x)}{\Ai(x)}$$

Now use [Bessel J](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Bessel+J) and [Bessel Y](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Bessel+Y):

$$\frac{\text J_\frac13(x)}{\text Y_\frac13(x)}=\frac4{\frac{\Ai\left(-\left(\frac32\right)^\frac23x^\frac23\right)}{\Bi\left(-\left(\frac32\right)^\frac23x^\frac23\right) }+\sqrt3}-\sqrt3\implies \frac{\Bi(x)}{\Ai(x)}=\frac{\frac4{1-\sqrt3 \frac{\text J_\frac13\left(\frac23(-x)^\frac32\right)}{\text Y_\frac13\left(\frac23(-x)^\frac32\right)}}-1}{\sqrt3}=\sqrt3$$

Here is the solution

$$\begin{align}\frac{\text J_\frac13\left(\frac23(-x)^\frac32\right)}{\text Y_\frac13\left(\frac23(-x)^\frac32\right)} =\sqrt3\iff \sqrt3\Ai(x)+\Bi(x)=0\implies x=-\left(\frac32\text y_{\frac13,\Bbb N+\frac16}\right)^\frac23\end{align}$$

which [**is true**](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=-sqrt%283%29-Bi%28-%283%2F2+BesselYZero%281%2F3%2C+19%2F6%29%29%5E%282%2F3%29%29%2FAi%28-%283%2F2+BesselYZero%281%2F3%2C+19%2F6%29%29%5E%282%2F3%29%29) with the $n$th natural number giving the $n$th solution.